# Take user input in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, user-input

Below is a simple python 2.7 code using **class** and **objects**.

```
class Student:
 def __init__(self,name,pref):
  self.name = name
  self.preference = pref

student1=Student("Tom","cce")

print(student1.name)
print(student1.preference)
```

How can this code be implemented so that the **name** and **preference** values(**string**) are taken using user-input(**raw_input()**)

Comment: Take user input, store it in a variable, pass the variables instead of literals.

Comment: `student1 = Student(raw_input("Enter your name"),raw_input("Enter your preference"))`

Comment: That did not work for me....can you give some more detail?below

Comment: Thnkyou @omri_saadon .Can you tell that is this perfect way in oop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is also a working code.

```
class Student:
 def __init__(self,name,pref):
  self.name = name
  self.preference = pref

student1=Student(raw_input("enter name:"),raw_input("enter branch:"))

print(student1.name)
print(student1.preference)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an example:**

```
class Student:
 def __init__(self,name,pref):
  self.name = name
  self.preference = pref

name1 = raw_input("Name:")
pref1 = raw_input("Preference:")

student1 = Student(name1, pref1)

print(student1.name)
print(student1.preference)
```